# Acessing beyond the allocated space and not getting segfault

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior

I allocated some space for a char pointer and tried to access beyond the allocated space but still getting no segmentation fault. my code is like below:

```
   char *src = malloc(4);
   strcpy(src, "1234");
   char *temp;
   for(int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++) {
        temp = src;
        src ++;     
        printf("ite ch  %c\n",src[0]);
    }
  printf("Still no segfault  %s\n",temp);
```

Now my question is: how can I go beyond the allocated space? Shouldn't I get segmentation fault?

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined. There is no guarantee it is detected at all.

Comment: C is a low-level langauge. It will happily allow you to shoot yourself in the foot all you like, and may or may not warn you.

Comment: "Shouldn't I get segmentation fault?" No.  C does not specify you _should_ seg fault.  It _might_ happen.  It is UB.  Other languages may specify that a seg fault must happen.  This often requires extra code or performance.  If  [training wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training_wheels) are needed, consider other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write past the end of a memory block allocated by malloc as you've done here, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Undefined behavior means the behavior of the program can't be predicted. It could crash, it could output strange results, or it could appear to work properly. Also, a seemingly unrelated change such as adding an unused local variable or a call to printf for debugging can change the way undefined behavior manifests itself.

To summarize, with undefined behavior, just because the program could crash doesn't mean it will.

Answer (score 0):

The malloc() function implementation is system and library specific.  One of the things that many memory allocation implementations have to deal with is memory fragmentation.

The question code allocates 4 bytes.  In order to minimize memory fragmentation, many systems actually allocate more than 4; perhaps a minimum of 16 bytes.  Doing so both satisfies the malloc(4) request, as well as keeps memory fragments (once the memory has been freed) to a minimum size of 16 bytes.  Hence a "memory fragment pool" of 16 byte fragments can be used to satisfy malloc() request from 1 to 16 bytes.

Many memory management systems maintain "memory fragment pools" of 16,32,64,128, (etc) bytes each.  For example, if a call of malloc(44) is made, a memory fragment from the 64 byte pool can satisfy the request.

On some systems, there is a provision to determine the actual size of the memory fragment returned by malloc().  On a Linux system, the function malloc_usable_size() performs this function.  OS X systems can use malloc_size().